# How can I divide output with a delimiter? (Linux, Bash, Regex)

Tags: regex, bash, delimiter

I would like to change

> Hi
>
> e·ver·y·bo·dy

to

> Hi
>
> e·ver·y·bo·dy
>
> e·ver·y·bo·
>
> e·ver·y·
>
> e·ver·
>
> e·

Comment: hint: google for `cut` or `awk`. & what have you tried?

Comment: anishane, thanks from help I received at AskUbuntu, I got `echo "e·ver·y·bo·dy" | awk -F· -v OFS=· '{print;for (i=NF;i>1;i--){$i="";print;NF--} }'`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
fun(){
line=$1
while [[ 1 ]]
do
echo $line
nline=${line%·*}                                                                                                                                                           
[[ "$nline" == "$line" ]] && break
line=$nline"·"
done
}

while read line
do
    fun "$line"
done < "your_input_file_name"
```

explain:

The fun function first echo the line. then cut the last `·*` part.If the cutted line match the old one,there is no more seprator left, so break the loop.If they dont match,assign the cutted line to old line and then loop to the echo part.

problem:

Cant figure out how to pass a varible to shell string function `${line%·*}`, so you should replace the other seprater manually

Comment: Hey amow, thanks for taking the time to help.
I tried your code, but it removed all of the dots instead of dividing by them.

I will probably end up using this:
`echo "e·ver·y·bo·dy" | awk -F· -v OFS=· '{print;for (i=NF;i>1;i--){$i="";print;NF--} }'`

Comment: @ericramos1990 sorry for that,my mistake.and your awk code is better.

Comment: No problem, and I got it using same question asked in AskUbuntu :D

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ne :1 -e 'p;s/\(.*·\)..*/\1/;t1'
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please ?